# DataFrame operation R

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, dplyr

I'm trying to assign a variable in data frame according to specific another column variable. i.e.

```
Dta = matrix(0,10000,2)
colnames(Dta) <- c("School_ID","Class_ID")
Dta = as_data_frame(Dta)
Dta$School_ID = sample(100)
Dta$School_ID = sort(Dta$School_ID)
for (i in unique(Dta$School_ID) ) Dta[Dta$School_ID == i,'Class_ID'] = sample(5)
```

Is there any solution by using group_by or other operators without a loop?

Comment: I believe there must be a way to avoid for loop. But please provide a reproducible example dataset.

Comment: I added a rep. example

Comment: Try: `Dta %>% group_by(School_ID) %>% mutate(Class_ID = sample(1:5,1))`.

Comment: It doesn't do what the previous code does. The previous one assigns 5 class ids within each school equally(20 class ids for whole schools) whereas yours assign the same class id for the whole school

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution from `dplyr`. `dt2` is the final output.

```
# Load package
library(dplyr)

dt <- data_frame(School_ID = rep(1:100, each = 100))

dt2 <- dt %>%
  group_by(School_ID) %>%
  mutate(Class_ID = rep(sample(5), 20))
```